# Adding objects to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, object, insert

I'm trying to insert a object into a array, but instead of insert into array, it prints in the screen the memory addresses.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@article = Article.new("test","test1")
@articles <<  @article     #this line causes the prints
```

And my view have this code:

```
<%=
    @articles.each do |a|
    a.titulo + " / " + a.texto
    end
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with how you render the `@articles`:

```
<%= @articles.each do |a| a.titulo + " / " + a.texto end %>
```

The return value of `each` is the array itself. You want to render each element within the array, so you should do something like this:

```
<% @articles.each do |a| %> 
  <%= a.titulo + " / " + a.texto %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely expected behavior. If `@articles` is indeed an array, this should work. Just check the array after the append and make sure the newly added element is there. If you are doing this from the console, then the printing you are seeing is probably console behavior and not `<<` behavior.

Because of the comment below, I'm changing my answer to reflect the actual problem. You are trying to render the enumerator to the view, and not the articles. Your view should look like:

```
<% @articles.each |a| %>
  <%= a.titulo + " / " + a.texto %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am running it in web, its prints the memory addresses in the web page.

Comment: How exactly are you printing it to the page?

Comment: I am doing this in the view to show the results <%=
    @articles.each do |a|
    a.titulo + " / " + a.texto
    end
    %>

Comment: @Afaria - you should add this to your post - your problem is here, not where you think it is...

Comment: I believe that is your problem. You are trying to render the enumerator to the view, not the articles themselves. You should be doing it something like: `<% @articles.each do |a| %> <%= a.titulo + " / " + a.texto %> <% end %>`

Answer (score 1):

You could force @articles to be an array like this:

```
@articles ||= []
```

Then add your @article like you were already doing

Comment: Good call. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create `@articles` as an `Array` before adding to it with `<<`.

*E.g.*,

```
class MyController < ...
  def your_method
    @articles ||= []
    @article = Article.new("test","test1")
    @articles <<  @article
  end

  ...
end
```

(and/or in a `before_` filter and/or...)

Comment: Having an `initialize` in a controller is not very idiomatic, I don't recommend it. Instead, I recommend a private method: `def articles; @articles ||= []; end;`

Comment: Yeah, `initialize` in a controller is going to cause problems. Don't do this. Instead use a `before_filter`.